# Initializer list to array

Tags: c++, arrays, class, constructor, initializer-list

As of now, I have a class `Permutation`, which has this:

```
public:
 int elements[N];
 Permutation(std::initializer_list<size_t> data): elements(data) {};
```

But when I try to compile, I get this:

> error: array initializer must be an initializer list

I've googled the hell out of the initialiser lists, though there is nothing that was useful/I could understand. So I do not have the tiniest idea about how to use the initialiser lists.

How do I write this constructor?

**UPDATE**

I also have this version:

```
public:
 int elements[N];
 Permutation(std::initializer_list<size_t> data): elements(new int[N]) {
     std::copy(data.begin(), data.end(), elements.begin(), elements.end());
 }
```

I'm pretty sure it's even more wrong, but if it's fixable, could someone tell me how to do this?

Comment: An initializer list like `{1, 2, 3}` should not be confused with `std::initializer_list`. IMO the standards committee really messed that up.

Comment: `std::vector` supports initialization from a `std::initializer_list` argument.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg So you are saying that I don't need it  if I want to do something like this `Permutation<3> tau {0, 2, 1};` ?

Comment: @M.M: no, `std::array` doesn't support `std::initializer_list`.

Comment: I'm saying you can't use a `std::initializer_list` to initialize an array, you need to use a loop in the constructor body to initialize each element in the array from the `std::initializer_list`. Oh and why do you have an `std::initializer_list<size_t>` when you have an `int` array? Shouldn't it be `std::initializer_list<int>`?

Comment: looks like you're stuck with `if (data.size() != N) throw.....` `std::copy(data.begin(), data.begin() + N, elements);` or similar

Comment: @JoachimPileborg This code was actually given to me to find mistakes; I don't have _any_ idea on how initialiser lists are supposed to work, so I didn't want to introduce even more errors

Comment: How about looking for [a reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list)? And then we should probably not say more. :)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I've seen this; I still don't understand how is this supposed to work in my case

Comment: If the code was given to you to find mistakes, isn't it kind of cheating to ask people here to fix the code? ;-)

Comment: @FrerichRaabe Oh, there is _way_ more mistakes than just this; it's just that I've never worked with `initialiser_list`s and I don't understand how to. Is it wrong to ask help on a subject you've never encountered before?

Comment: @FrerichRaabe - I don't find it "cheating". I would call it "studying". As long as OP learns something, the goal has been reached. Whether OP learns from a book or SO seems the same to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second approach is close. It needs minor adjustments.

```
Permutation(std::initializer_list<int> data) : elements{}
{
   size_t size = data.size();
   if ( size <= N )
   {
      std::copy(data.begin(), data.end(), std::begin(elements));
   }
   else
   {
      std::copy(data.begin(), data.begin()+N, std::begin(elements));
   }
}
```

Comment: Probably it should check that we do not write off the end of `elements`; and also value-initialize unused elements if the list was too short.

Comment: @M.M This I can handle myself; I only need to understand the syntax and basics

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I will try this; If everything works well I will accept this